# Best unit or building to fight with Apaches

Tags: command-and-conquer-generals

I know that C&C Generals is an old game, but there are a lot of players who like this game. USA Apache unit is one of the most dangerous units in the game. So how can I fight with them with the lowest losses and the maximum injuries?

[image]

Comment: use the best anti air unit for your country of choice?

Comment: I use the defending buildings. but they are very weak vs a little big group of apaches.

Answer (score 2):

Apaches have no air-to-air weapons, so if you are playing USA or China then jets would be a good option.  They would allow you to take apaches out with no losses.